# Flurry Analytics 6.4.2 - No data showing up in real-time dashboard

Tags: java, android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I've recently implemented the flurry analytics framework doing this:

- importation of the library with jcenter() in the build.gradle
- Addition of the following code to the Application

  ```
      new FlurryAgent.Builder()
          .withLogEnabled(false)
          .build(this, Constants.Flurry.API_KEY);
  ```

I've double checked that:

- the code initializing Flurry is hit
- My API_KEY is correct
- The manifest allow the network permission
- I've done several sessions and close & re-open the app to get it to send data

Yet i don't get anything in the Flurry Analytics real-time dashboard (Even days after the session)

I'm targeting API 19 to 23, so i don't have to specifically call start & end sessions.

I followed the documentation, what am i missing ?

Comment: flurry developed by yahoo is too slow to use in real time

Comment: Use crashlytics of twitter its good and light weight.

Comment: What's the approximate delay between the session end and the apparition of the data in the dashboard ?

EDIT: I am also using crashlytics, i have both actually. Could there be any conflicts between them ?